# Inverse Split Sequence and Plot

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have a time series:

```
            Close
2018-01-01  66.659485
2018-01-02  66.659485
2018-01-03  65.877713
2018-01-04  66.791399
2018-01-05  67.968765
2018-01-06  96.900002
2018-01-07  96.900002
2018-01-08  96.900002
2018-01-09  96.349998
2018-01-10  95.519997
```

I split into n-day sequences (3 days for example)

```
        Col_0       Col_1       Col_2
0   66.659485   66.659485   65.877713
1   66.659485   65.877713   66.791399
2   65.877713   66.791399   67.968765
3   66.791399   67.968765   96.900002
4   67.968765   96.900002   96.900002
5   96.900002   96.900002   96.900002
6   96.900002   96.900002   96.349998
```

Using a clustering algorithm, such as KMeans, I manage to assign each sequence to a clusters  (this is an example):

```
        Col_0       Col_1       Col_2    Cluster
0   66.659485   66.659485   65.877713          0 
1   66.659485   65.877713   66.791399          0
2   65.877713   66.791399   67.968765          1
3   66.791399   67.968765   96.900002          0
4   67.968765   96.900002   96.900002          1
5   96.900002   96.900002   96.900002          0
6   96.900002   96.900002   96.349998          0
```

My question is: how can I plot the original time series with the clusters in different colors? I have been trying using the transpose .T but with no success.

Comment: How do you define the n days? consecutive? What is there was an extra `2018-01-10`?

Comment: Yes, the n-days are consecutives. The time series is large (I only wrote several lines).

Comment: Is this dummy data? The output doesn't match the input, making it unclear to see the logic

Comment: Thanks @mozway; yes, it is dummy data, it is just to see how to plot the time series with the clusters

Comment: Please provide an example with matching in/out data (use 1/2/3/4 for clarity), it's currently unclear in which direction the reshaping should happen

Comment: The data matches now

Comment: Ernesto, the same point can be in two different clusters. Take for example the 3rd value `65.877713`, which is both in sequence 1 and 2, whose cluster value is 0 and 1 respectively. That makes it more difficult to assign a unique color.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) to get a [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

out = pd.DataFrame(sliding_window_view(df['Close'], 3)).add_prefix('Col_')
```

output:

```
       Col_0      Col_1      Col_2
0  66.659485  66.659485  65.877713
1  66.659485  65.877713  66.791399
2  65.877713  66.791399  67.968765
3  66.791399  67.968765  96.900002
4  67.968765  96.900002  96.900002
5  96.900002  96.900002  96.900002
6  96.900002  96.900002  96.349998
7  96.900002  96.349998  95.519997
```

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut; but, how could I plot the initial time series with the clusters in  different colors?

Comment: Can you provide a mock-up of the expected graph?